# Поиск чисел удовлетворяющих условию

Tags: алгоритм, комбинаторика

Необходимо написать программу, которая определяет количество троек натуральных чисел (x,y,z), таких что:

**0 < x < y < z < N,**

Где N - натуральное число, **0 < N < 1000**

Понимаю, что задача состоит в правильном использовании комбинаторных формул. Однако идей нет. Вариант в лоб (через 3 цикла и перебор не подходит для меня). Нет идей. Не нужно ничего писать, если можно подтолкните к правильному решению.

Comment: Сколько всего возможно троек **разных** чисел? 999*998*997. Сколько вариантов тройки существует? 1*2*3. Сколько из них подходит? 1. Итого (999*998*997)/((1*2*3)/1) считай сам...

Comment: @Akina всё так, только если имелось ввиду для максимального `N`, то оно тут `999` и соответственно в числителе `998*997*996`. Ну и соответственно в общем виде будет `(N-1)*(N-2)*(N-3)/6` и отсутствие решений для `N<4`

Comment: @yolosora угу...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Как уже написали в комментариях, посчитать число троек (`x`, `y`, `z`) натуральных чисел, таких что

```
0 < x < y < z < N
```

можно так:

- Сначала уберём условие упорядоченности, то есть посчитаем число троек (`x`, `y`, `z`), таких что каждое из трёх чисел больше нуля и меньше `N`

  Получится `N - 1` * `N - 2` * `N - 3` троек (первое число можно выбрать `N - 1` способами, второе `N - 2` способами, ...)
- Теперь рассмотрим три различных числа, например {1, 2, 3}. Всего троек, составленных из этих чисел будет `6 = 3 * 2 * 1` штук (следствие предыдущего пункта для `N` равного `3+1`). Нам подходит ровно одна из этих шести троек — когда числа стоят по возрастанию

Таким образом, ответ равен `(N - 1) * (N - 2) * (N - 3) / 6`